# function to make a list of all sass variables in scope

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, colors, sass

I have a file that assigns hex values to variables. for example;

```
$brown-50: #efebe9;
$brown-100: #d7ccc8;
$brown-200: #bcaaa4;
$brown-300: #a1887f;
```

I'm looking for a way of taking all the variables in the current scope and placing them in a list to iterate though so I can generate a list that would work effectively like:

```
$list: (
$brown-50
$brown-100
$brown-200
$brown-300
)
```

Comment: My ruby skills are non existent, I have tried making the whole file into a list, which didn't work. I tried making the whole thing a map, however it seems inflexible. I'm tempted just to create the list manually. the goal is to be able to iterate over the variables using native sass.

Comment: Show us code segments that you tried but didn't work as expected, only then can we start to help.